# Cache graph with hierarchy

Tags: caching, graph

I'm looking to build a graph that's tied to any caching system that I can interact with. Its only goal is when an item is deleted, based on its "linked items", to also delete these. A partial rebuild of the cache, if you will.

For example, in an action-driven system, my object would be listening for the action `post_updated` to be fired. It will then look inside my graph and see that values with the keys `post_123_gallery, post_123_recipe, post_123_small_images` need to be deleted and the cache for these need to be rebuild.

I have some schematics I came up with to try to represent this graph/tree in the memory:

```
[
    <context> 'page:post_1' => [
        keys => [
            'page:post_1:gallery:gallery_3257',
            'page:post_1:recipes:recipe_2',
        ],
        actions => [
            'post_updated',
            'gallery_created',
            'recipe_created',
        ]
    ]
]
```

The first allows for contextualization of my values. Every value I saved will be under a prefix, which is its context, as decided by the developers. For example, when I'm on a post page and I'm saving new data, the system will save the supposed cached values under these prefixed keys.

```
[
    <key>'post_1:gallery_3257' => [
        'actions_to_clear_on' => [
            'post_updated',
            'gallery_created'
        ],
        'linked_to' => [
            'post_1:recipes:recipe_2'
        ]
    ]
]
```

The second one doesn't have the concept of context (but it's expected of developers to name things in a natural, predictable way), rather, each key is treated as an individual that can have other linked keys. When one key gets deleted, whatever is under `linked_to` also gets deleted.

In my head, I'm stuck. Something doesn't feel right about either of the approaches in the sense that, at their core, they won't work. One thing that comes to mind is that the first approach is totally flawed, a key(A) can depend on another key(B), and (B) can depend on multiple keys on its own. Basically, a small deletion can quickly turn into a mammoth of chain deletes.

Comment: You appear to be describing garbage collection... what language are you needing this in?

Comment: @MartinK PHP, but it doesn't matter, I can implement anything if I see the schematics.

Comment: well in a garbage collected environment, you usually don't have to solve this problems. objects which are no longer reachable via other objects get deleted by the GC